# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I'm trying to work through Beginning Hibernate 2nd edition, and I'm stuck trying to put together the simple working example with HSQLDB.

When I run `ant populateMessages`, I get

```
[java] org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: sample.entity.Message
[java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
[java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:747)
...
```

Here's what I've got:

**Message.java**

```
package sample.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Message
{
    private String messageText;
    private Integer id;

    public Message( String messageText )
    {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public Message()
    {
    }

    public String getMessageText()
    {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText)
    {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**PopulateMessages.java**

```
package sample;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import sample.entity.Message;

import java.util.Date;

public class PopulateMessages
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Message m1 = new Message("Hibernated a  messages on " + new Date());
        session.save(m1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**build.properties**

```
# Path to the hibernate install directory
hibernate.home=C:/hibernate/hibernate-3.5.6
# Path to the hibernate-tools install directory
hibernate.tools.home=C:/hibernate/hibernate-tools
# Path to hibernate-tools.jar relative to hibernate.tools.home
hibernate.tools.path=/plugins/org.hibernate.eclipse_3.3.1.v201006011046R-H111-GA/lib/tools
# Path to hibernate-tools hibernate libraries relative to hibernate.tools.home
hibernate.tools.lib.path=/plugins/org.hibernate.eclipse_3.3.1.v201006011046R-H111-GA/lib/hibernate
# Path to the SLF4J implementation JAR for the logging framework to use
slf4j.implementation.jar=lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar
# Path to the HSQL DB install directory
hsql.home=C:/hsqldb
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb;shutdown=true
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
<!-- "Import" the mapping resources here -->
<mapping class="sample.entity.Message"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**build.xml**

```
<project name="sample">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="bin" location="bin"/>
    <property name="sql" location="sql"/>
    <property name="hibernate.tools"
              value="${hibernate.tools.home}${hibernate.tools.path}"/>
    <path id="classpath.base">
        <pathelement location="${src}"/>
        <pathelement location="${bin}"/>
        <pathelement location="${hibernate.home}/hibernate3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${slf4j.implementation.jar}"/>
        <fileset dir="${hibernate.home}/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${hsql.home}/lib/hsqldb.jar"/>
  <fileset dir="./lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>
<path id="classpath.tools">
    <path refid="classpath.base"/>
    <pathelement
            location="${hibernate.tools.home}/${hibernate.tools.lib.path}/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement
            location="${hibernate.tools}/freemarker.jar"/>
    <pathelement
            location="${hibernate.tools}/hibernate-tools.jar"/>
</path>
<taskdef name="htools"
         classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"
         classpathref="classpath.tools"/>
<target name="exportDDL" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${sql}"/>
    <htools destdir="${sql}">
        <classpath refid="classpath.tools"/>
        <annotationconfiguration
                configurationfile="${src}/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <hbm2ddl drop="true" outputfilename="sample.sql"/>
    </htools>
</target>
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" classpathref="classpath.base"/>
</target>
<target name="populateMessages" depends="compile">
    <java classname="sample.PopulateMessages" classpathref="classpath.base"/>
</target>
<target name="listMessages" depends="compile">
    <java classname="sample.ListMessages" classpathref="classpath.base"/>
</target>
```

Comment: +1 For the detailed question. I have encountered the same problem and and looking at your hibernate.cfg.xml showed me my problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You entity is not correctly annotated, you **must** use the [`@javax.persistence.Entity`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) annotation. You can use the Hibernate extension [`@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Entity.html) to go beyond what JPA has to offer but the Hibernate annotation is not a replacement, it's a complement.

So change your code into:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Message { 
    ...  
}
```

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.4. Hibernate Annotation Extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec)

Comment: ah, the Note about Entity being mandatory is new to me (I've never used the hibernate annotation). I spotted that piece (see my update), but wasn't sure it is the answer :) (+1)

Comment: @Bozho Can't say about the note but I'm sure that hibernate annotation has always been a complement, not a replacement. +1 for your update too then.

Comment: I'll test. I never, ever would have caught this.

Comment: @Stefan Well, that's a vicious issue and I detected it during an Nth scan of the code after chatting with Bozho. Actually, it's writing things that gave me an idea of what the problem could be.

Comment: But what if the required class that is an entity is from another library? Is there a way around using `@Entity`?

Answer (score 12):

You should call `.addAnnotatedClass(Message.class)` on your `AnnotationConfiguration`.

If you want your entities to be auto-discovered, use `EntityManager` (JPA)

([Reference](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=954644&start=0))

Update: it appears you have listed the class in hibernate.cfg.xml. So auto-discovery is not necessary. Btw, try `javax.persistence.Entity`

Comment: No, the OP shouldn't have to do that, the entity is declared in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent hmm, missed that line. Then it is strange, since by default the `Configuration.configure()` looks for hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Yeah I agree, this is strange. I would expect things to fail totally (the .cfg.xml is not found), not "partially". Activating logging might help but I'm too lazy to set up an Ant build to reproduce :)

Comment: LOL, I spotted the problem :)

Comment: @Pascal Thivent and it is? :)

Comment: Posted (firefox went crazy, had to reboot, make a coffee, etc).

Answer (score 1):

In case if you get this exception in `SpringBoot` application even though the entities are annotated with `Entity` annotation, it might be due to the spring not aware of where to scan for entities

To explicitly specify the package, add below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"model.package.name"})
public class SpringBootApp {...}
```

note: If you model classes resides in the same or sub packages of `SpringBootApplication` annotated class, no need to explicitly declare the `EntityScan`, by default it will scan

Answer (score 1):

Use below line of code in the case of Spring Boot Application 
Add in Spring Boot Main Class **@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=YourClassName.class)**

Answer (score 1):

use below line of code in the case of spring boot applications.

**@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=YourClassName.class)**

Answer (score 0):

you should add all the entity files in the .addAnnotatedClass(Class) method, if the class needs to be auto discovered.

use this link, it might help..

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I switched to `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`. I was using `entity.hbm.xml` before.

I found that My class was missing following annotation which resolved the issue in my case:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTestEntity")
@XmlRootElement
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***import javax.persistence.Entity;***
Instead of ***import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;***

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved After adding
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
new String[] { "com.springhibernate.model" });
Tested this Functionality in spring boot latest version 2.1.2.

Full Method:

```
 @Bean( name="sessionFactoryConfig")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryConfig() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceConfig());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.springhibernate.model" });

        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernatePropertiesConfig());

        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable entity scan by adding below annotation on Application .java
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=YourEntityClassName.class)

Or you can set the packageToScan in your session factory.
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(“com.all.entity”);

Answer (score 0):

check that entity is defined in hibernate.cfg.xml or not.

Answer (score -2):

In hibernate.cfg.xml , please put following code

```
<mapping class="class/bo name"/>
```