# spring boot - how to avoid org.hibernate.MappingException Unknown entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

in my spring boot / hibernate application, I have a data access class "CusttableDao":

```
import com.mycompany.myproduct.data.models.Custtable;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class CusttableDao {

    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CusttableDao.class);

  public void update(Custtable custtable) {
    entityManager.merge(custtable);
    return;
  }

  public Custtable getById(Class<Custtable> class1, CusttableCompositeKey custtableCompositeKey) {
        Custtable ct = entityManager.find(Custtable.class, custtableCompositeKey);
        LOG.debug("customer.ct.accountNum:  " + ct.getAccountnum());
        return entityManager.find(Custtable.class, custtableCompositeKey);
    }
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

When it comes to executing the getById method, I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mycompany.myproduct.data.models.Custtable
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2565)
```

Here is the actual Custtable definition, which has the proper @Entity annotation:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import com.mycompany.myproduct.data.models.CusttableCompositeKey;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Custtable implements java.io.Serializable {
```

What should I change / add to avoid this error?

Comment: I could not add answer here since its duplicated, I have added answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32939165/3344829, could you check if it helps

Comment: I have made an edit to demonstrate the actual Custtable class, to show that I already have the @Entity annotation on my class

Comment: Have you read my answer fully? added EntityScan annotation with entities packages?

Comment: When I added @EntityScan({"com.mycompany.myproduct.data.models.Custtable"})  , I got this:  IllegalStateException: Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate your entity with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation like described here? [org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001795/org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity#4005613)

Comment: To solve this, I ended up adding the following line to application.properties:   entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.myconpany.myproduct.data